# make checkboxes for a has_many :through association using Formtastic

Tags: activeadmin, formtastic

I have this models :

**Offer**

```
class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :lists
    has_many :documents
end
```

**List**

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :offer
    has_many :entries, :dependent => :destroy

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :entries, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

**Entry**

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :list
    belongs_to :document
end
```

**User**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many   :lists, :dependent => :destroy                
end
```

I'm using [ActiveAdmin](http://activeadmin.info/), before my change I had this form for **List** :

```
form do |f|
    f.inputs "Détails Utilisateurs" do 
        f.input :user
    end
    f.inputs "Accès" do 
        f.has_many :entries, {:title => '', :link => 'Ajouter un document'} do |c| 
            c.inputs '' do
                if not c.object.id.nil?
                    c.input :_destroy, :as => :boolean, :label => "Supprimer l'accès"
                end
                c.input :document, :include_blank => false, :collection => offer.documents, :member_label => :to_label
            end 
        end 
    end 
    f.buttons 
end
```

But now I want to use checkbox instead of add/remove link buttons so I do something more like this :

```
form do |f|
    f.inputs "Détails Utilisateurs" do 
        f.input :user
    end
    f.inputs "Accès" do 
        f.input :entries, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => offer.documents
    end 
    f.buttons 
end
```

But I havn't the correct name in checkbox, I have try with :name params and :html_options but they have no effect.
Any idea to fix this ?

Comment: Maybe is a little bit late and you found the solution already...

Answer (score 0):

Could you try with this?

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs "Détails Utilisateurs" do 
    f.input :user
  end
  f.inputs "Accès" do
    offer.documents.each do |document|
      f.input document,
        label: document,
        as: :boolean do
          f.check_box document, {}, "true", "false"
        end
    end
  end
  f.buttons 
end
```

Hope it helps!